# Principal coordinates analysis with gower distance

Tags: r, vegan

I'm trying to visualize a distance matrix using the function `capscale` from vegan. However, I find that I cannot, because it returns only a single axis when used with a particular distance metric (the "gower" distance) and I don't understand why this is so.

```r
library(vegan)
#> Warning: package 'vegan' was built under R version 3.4.3
#> Loading required package: permute
#> Loading required package: lattice
#> This is vegan 2.4-5
sp1 <- c(3, 3, 0, 0, 0)
sp2 <- c(0, 3, 0, 0, 1)
sp3 <- c(0, 0, 3, 3, 1)
sp4 <- c(0, 0, 0, 3, 1)
sp5 <- c(0, 2, 0, 0, 1)
sp6 <- c(0, 2, 0, 0, 1)
sp7 <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
sp8 <- c(0, 0, 0, 2, 1)

sp_mat <- rbind(sp1, sp2, sp3, sp4,
                sp5, sp6, sp7, sp8)
colnames(sp_mat) <- letters[1:5]

sp_gow <- vegdist(sp_mat, method = "gower")

capscale(sp_gow ~ 1)
#> Call: capscale(formula = sp_gow ~ 1)
#> 
#>               Inertia Rank
#> Total          0.6489     
#> Unconstrained  0.6489    1
#> Inertia is squared Gower distance 
#> 
#> Eigenvalues for unconstrained axes:
#>   MDS1 
#> 0.6489
```

This happens even though the distance matrix is of the dimension we expect:

```r
sp_gow
#>            sp1        sp2        sp3        sp4        sp5        sp6
#> sp2 0.40000000                                                       
#> sp3 1.00000000 0.60000000                                            
#> sp4 0.80000000 0.40000000 0.20000000                                 
#> sp5 0.46666667 0.06666667 0.53333333 0.33333333                      
#> sp6 0.46666667 0.06666667 0.53333333 0.33333333 0.00000000           
#> sp7 0.66666667 0.26666667 0.33333333 0.13333333 0.20000000 0.20000000
#> sp8 0.73333333 0.33333333 0.26666667 0.06666667 0.26666667 0.26666667
#>            sp7
#> sp2           
#> sp3           
#> sp4           
#> sp5           
#> sp6           
#> sp7           
#> sp8 0.06666667
```

With a different distance measure it works fine:

```r
sp_gow <- vegdist(sp_mat, method = "bray")

capscale(sp_gow ~ 1)
#> Call: capscale(formula = sp_gow ~ 1)
#> 
#>                 Inertia Eigenvals Rank
#> Total          1.453564  1.456806     
#> Unconstrained  1.453564  1.456806    5
#> Imaginary               -0.003243    1
#> Inertia is squared Bray distance 
#> 
#> Eigenvalues for unconstrained axes:
#>   MDS1   MDS2   MDS3   MDS4   MDS5 
#> 1.1350 0.2578 0.0552 0.0087 0.0001
```

Answer (score 2):

Without contraints, `capscale` produces unconstrained principal coordinates analysis. However, it uses the function `wcmdscale` rather than `cmdscale` to do the calculations, and the two functions differ in how they deal with low eigenvalues. With your data:

```
> cmdscale(sp_gow, eig = TRUE)
$points
          [,1]          [,2]
sp1 -0.5666667  1.497751e-08
sp2 -0.1666667 -4.315554e-09
sp3  0.4333333  1.122044e-08
sp4  0.2333333  6.041776e-09
sp5 -0.1000000 -2.589333e-09
sp6 -0.1000000 -2.589333e-09
sp7  0.1000000  2.589333e-09
sp8  0.1666667  4.315554e-09

$eig
[1]  6.488889e-01  4.440892e-16  2.610151e-17  1.676474e-17  8.672740e-19
[6]  6.523746e-19 -1.829633e-33 -1.316088e-17
```

Compare this to `wcmdscale`:

```
> wcmdscale(sp_gow, eig = TRUE)
Call: wcmdscale(d = sp_gow, eig = TRUE)

      Inertia Rank
Total  0.6489    1

Results have 8 points, 1 axes

Eigenvalues:
[1] 0.6489

Weights: Constant

> scores(wcmdscale(sp_gow, eig = TRUE))
          Dim1
sp1 -0.5666667
sp2 -0.1666667
sp3  0.4333333
sp4  0.2333333
sp5 -0.1000000
sp6 -0.1000000
sp7  0.1000000
sp8  0.1666667
```

Notice that the first vector is identical for both functions. `wcmdscale` doesn't show us the second vector. But we can see it in the `cmdscale` output. Further, the eigenvalues for the second and subsequent vectors in `cmdscale` are within rounding error of zero. `wcmdscale` removes all these tiny values.

All of which means that `capscale` has done a PCoA with your data, only it has suppressed all the axes with eigenvalues <= 0. If you plot the output from `cmdscale` you can see this for yourself:

```
plot(cmdscale(sp_gow, eig = TRUE)$points, asp = 1)
```

[image]